# formatting phone number in c++

Tags: c++

Please assist, I am trying to format a phone number like `(111)111-1111`. I have the following code which works but I would like to write much shorter.

```
int main(){

    string phone_number;

    cin >> phone_number;
    cout<<"(";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cout << phone_number[i];
    }

    cout << ")";
    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
      cout << phone_number[i];
    }

    cout << "-";

    for(int i = 6; i < 10; i++) {
      cout << phone_number[i];
    }

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

please assist

Comment: Before you start trying to write *shorter* code, please take the time to *indent* your code properly. For example, normally the body of a loop is indented some number of spaces from the enclosing `for` and `}`. Your code will be unacceptable to most readers until you start doing this consistently.

Comment: Why does it need to be shorter?

Comment: This works only for a subset of phone numbers (US numbers). What if I enter `0049 30 12345678` or `+49 30 12345678`?

Comment: This seems like a classic homework question.  If so, I and many others would greatly appreciate tagging it as such so that we can provide "appropriate" answers (i.e. not providing you the code, which IMO is tantamount to cheating).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
cout << "(" << phone_number.substr(0,3) << ")"
     << phone_number.substr(3,3) << "-" << phone_number.substr(6,4) << endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [string::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/). But since you are taking a string as input, why wouldn't you give the input in format you need. Any how, this is how it can be done with out any loops if you wish to modify the string. In case you don't wish to change the original string then store the modified to a different temporary variable.

```
string phone_number = "123456789";
phone_number = phone_number.insert( 0, "(" );  // Original string is modified

// Rest can be achieved in similar fashion

cout << phone_number << endl;
```

Comment: Perfect! I want to insert a space between the numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    if (i == 0) std::cout << '(';
    else if (i == 3) std::cout << ')';
    else if (i == 6) std::cout << '-';
    std::cout << phone_number[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably wouldn't be good to change your data just to format.

```
string str(phn);

// Format Phone# 1: void function
printf("(%s)%s-%s", 
    str.substr(0,3).c_str(), 
    str.substr(3,3).c_str(), 
    str.substr(6, 4).c_str());

// Format Phone# 2: returns std::string&
   stringstream p;
   p << "(" << str.substr(0, 3) << ")"
    << str.substr(3, 3) << "-"
    << str.substr(6, 4);

   return p.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the question as to *why* you want to write this "shorter" ...

```
printf("(%c%c%c)%c%c%c-%c%c%c%c\n", phone_number[0], phone_number[1], phone_number[2],
                                    phone_number[3], phone_number[4], phone_number[5],
                                    phone_number[6], phone_number[7], phone_number[8],
                                    phone_number[9]);
```

That being said - your code (nor this) checks to see if there's actually 10 numbers present, or if they're numbers at all. *That* above all is more important than wanting it "shorter".

Comment: Thx - fingers faster than brain at times. I was trying to get to the last part more so than the printf statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too short, not too long. Any input from the user must always be checked for validity. For instance, what if the used already entered the punctuation, so that `phone_number` contains "(111)111-1111"? Then your code would output "((11)-)11-1-11" (I think). This is not what you want. At the very least, you must throw out all non-digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string phone_number;

    cin >> phone_number;
    cout<<"(";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cout << phone_number[i];
    }

    cout << ")";
    for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
      cout << phone_number[i];
    }

    cout << "-";

    for(int i = 6; i < 10; i++) {
      cout << phone_number[i];
    }

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30467264)